# Convert general regex to bash proof regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I have the following regex that checks for a password policy. it is validated to work:

`(^([zZ]\d{3})*$)|((?=.{9,})(?=.*?[^\w\s])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*)`

I want to use the regex in a bash script to validate a psssword the following way :

```
echo $password | grep "(^([zZ]\d{3})*$)|((?=.{9,})(?=.*?[^\w\s])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*)"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
```

This does not work in bash.
My question is :

How do i convert this "pure" regex to a one that work in bash ? which characters do i need to escape, what is the correct way to pass the regex to grep ? are there any other things i need to look out for ?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question: This is a strange password policy. One valid set of passwords starts with a `z` and has exactly three digits after that? My *phone* could crack that in a few seconds :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker I'm not a regex expert, but this should match the policy `at least 9 characters, with at least one character from each of the 4 character classes (alphabetic lower and upper case; numeric, symbols).` You are correct though, I should correct the first part

Comment: It's even worse: Even the empty string is valid as a password! I'll add an analysis to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be difficult.

Standard `grep` has limited capabilities. It only supports POSIX extended regular expressions which do not recognize the [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) your regex relies on.

If you have GNU `grep` on your machine, you can pass it the `-P` or `--perl-regexp` parameter, allowing it to use Perl compatible regular expressions. Then your regex should work.

As mentioned in my comment, the regex as-is is not suitable for passwort validation. It allows passwords like `z000` or even the empty string:

```
(                 # Either match and capture...
 ^                #  Start of the string
 (                #  Match (and capture, uselessly in this case)
  [zZ]            #  case-insensitive z
  \d{3}           #  three digits
 )*               #  zero(!) or more times
 $                #  until the end of the string
)                 # End of first group.
|                 # OR
(                 # match and capture...
  (?=.{9,})       #  a string that's at least 9 characters long,
  (?=.*?[^\w\s])  #  contains at least one non-alnum, non-space character,
  (?=.*?[0-9])    #  at least one ASCII digit
  (?=.*?[A-Z])    #  at least one ASCII uppercase letter
  .*?[a-z].*      #  and at least one ASCII lowercase letter
)                 # no anchor to start/end of string...
```

Better use

```
^(?=.{9})(?=.*?[^\w\s])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*$
```

Comment: Thanks. would it be easier to do if i ran perl form bash ? also, what modifications would i have to do to the regex ? i would still need to escape the special characters right ?